# Latex Text Box with colored background that breaks as normal text

Tags: colorbox

I want to define a command, lets say

```
\quote{
This is a .... very long quote
}
```

that has a solid colored (in my case light gray) background, and ideally a colored line on the left side.

however, it should allow formatting and should break pages just like normal text. At the moment, I am using a colorbox that just continues on the same page on and on until there is no "paper" left.

```
\NewEnviron{myquote}{
    \colorbox{medium}{
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \BODY
        }
    }
}

\newcommand\quote[1]{
    \begin{myquote}
        #1
    \end{myquote}
}
```

Comment: I think you need `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have an example with `tcolorbox`. Colors and margins can be easily adapted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myquote}[1][]{%
    colback=black!5,
    colframe=black!5,
    notitle,
    sharp corners,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{red!80!black},
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{myquote}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tobi Thank you for accepting my answer. I've changed it after your acceptance because the new solution doesn't show the frame artifact behind the box. Hope it helps.